# bower_component jquery plugins not being invoked in angularjs app

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins

## Overview

I have several jQuery plugins that I'm intending to use in an AngularJS application.  I install my jQuery plugins via bower.  I use gulp-inject to put those dependencies in my main html.  I load jquery before I load angular.  I'm in the process of taking a template I obtained and organizing it similarly to how John Papa does with his [Hot Towel AngularJS generator](https://github.com/johnpapa/generator-hottowel).

## Problem

Libraries intended to extend jQuery are not being invoked.  Those files are loaded, but the extension on jQuery is never made.  For example, take these two jQuery plugins: [remarkable-bootstrap-notify](https://github.com/mouse0270/bootstrap-notify), and [jquery.sparkline](https://github.com/gwatts/jquery.sparkline).  Both of these, when loaded into the page, give an error saying that one of the functions I'm invoking that come from these libraries, does not exist.

---

## What I've tried

If I put a breakpoint in the files loaded in the browser, I notice that the factory code above does get called, but the code that does the extending (adding new functions) does not get run.  If I alter the `remarkable-bootstrap-notify` file that is loaded into my page by adding a `...}(jQuery)))` where it just read `...}))` before, suddenly that library begins working.

I tried this same fix on the `jquery.sparkline` library, but this does not make the library work.

This is not an ideal fix, obviously, because next time I bring that library in through bower, my changes are no longer there, breaking my app's features that depend on these libraries.

#### Note

I am attempting to use these jQuery plugins inside directives.  This wasn't pre-emptive thinking, but I have been reading EVERYWHERE that this is the fix to people's problems that are similar to my own.  However, this makes no difference for me.

#### Update

I have applied this "fix" to 3 libraries now, temporarily fixing the issue (jquery.sparkline, jquery.easypiechart, and bootstrap-notify).  My question now has an update to be more specific in hopes of a response.

---

## Question(s)

Having an AngularJS app with jQuery plugin dependencies doesn't seem like a silly thing to attempt, and I assumed this would be fairly straight-forward.  What could I be missing that usually allows this to work?  Is there something I can do that will work with all of these dependencies I'm bringing in through bower?

#### Update

There are now 3 libraries that are in my `bower_components` folder that need a manual edit just to work.  Graphically speaking, I must add the following (highlighted in the image below) just for the library to work in my application:

[image: This is just an example of what appears at the top of these typical jQuery plugins]

*(This is just an example of what appears at the top of these typical jQuery plugins)*

Rephrased question: What am I doing when I add the `...(jQuery)...` more specifically than, "I'm invoking the anonymous function, passing the `jQuery` object in as a param."  I get that much.  But why isn't this included in the libraries I'm downloading via bower?  What about my application forces me to make these manual edits?  This can't be how these libraries are normally used...

Comment: Could you set up a minimal jsfiddle in which you're getting the errors?

Comment: I'll attempt to.  Failed at that several times thus far.

Comment: @JakeSmith Does your problem also appear if you create a minimal example just with jQuery and the plugins?

Comment: @ssc-hrep3, Not so far :(

Comment: So, your problem occurs only when using the jQuery libraries in an angular directive or in an angular controller?

Comment: @ssc-hrep3, Seems to be that way.  johan is becoming more and more right about how I should move forward.  I just wish I could understand why following better practices as far as app architecture and using tools like bower (unlike the hardcoded and out of date libraries in the template I bought) broke the app.  I thought i was introducing stability, not showcasing the fragility.

Answer (score 4):

Quick question: what jQuery plugins are you talking about? Why try and hack jQuery code into Angular, where you can usually find the same or better plugins already written for Angular.

remarkable-bootstrap-notify can be replaced by [AngularJS-toaster](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster)

jquery.sparkline can be replaced by [Angular-chart](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/)

This is from docs.angularjs.org:

**DOM Manipulation**

Stop trying to use jQuery to modify the DOM in controllers. Really. That includes adding elements, removing elements, retrieving their contents, showing and hiding them. Use built-in directives, or write your own where necessary, to do your DOM manipulation. See below about duplicating functionality.

If you're struggling to break the habit, consider removing jQuery from your app. Really. Angular has the $http service and powerful directives that make it almost always unnecessary. Angular's bundled jQLite has a handful of the features most commonly used in writing Angular directives, especially binding to events.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions.  I bought a template and it has a lot of code.  So yes, this is one solution.  One I was didn't want to have to move towards immediately.  This is a fairly large codebase I adopted.  As far as using jQuery for DOM manipulation in my controllers, I completely agree that that is a big no-no.  However, I'm only calling the init functions of those jQuery libraries.  I'm not sure if this really answers my question either.  Take Angular out of the equation and the same question still stands.  Why would I have to add that invocation at the end manually?

Comment: You should adopt this answer as your solution and replace these jquery libraries with their angular equivalents. You are right that this doesn't answer the question about why you need to explicitly require jquery to make it work, but it's probably a waste of your time because you should be using angular services and libraries to begin with. 

As a general rule, if you ever find yourself having to overwrite a library file in your bower directory you need to reframe what your problem is. In this case, it's trying to jam these unnecessary jquery libraries into an angular app.

Comment: @Jake Smith there is nothing wrong with buying a template, I also bought a template to kick start my project, but I bought an Angular template. This way you learn how other dev's put such a project together, and learn through reading their code. I also stuck with Angular with all my libraries and plugins, and so far have no problems at all.

Comment: @johan, This was an angular template, but for some reason it included angular essentially invoking jquery libraries.  I wish I would have known what I was buying before I bought it.  By the way, thanks for your help!

Comment: @JakeSmith I would leave a bad review, warn others against the template, I don't know if it is allowed, post a link so other dev's won't buy the template. I bought the minovate template and works great. http://tattek.sk/minovate/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I really appreciate it.